# C++ calculating Artctan Function for class

Tags: c++, function, class

I have to create a function for Arctan WITHOUT using cmath

The formula is ctan (x) = x – x^3/3 + x^5/5 – x^7/7 + x^9/9 - …

Heres what I have, please tell me why its not working...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


double ArcTan(double x) {

double y = 7;
double specialx = pow(x,y)/y;
double first;
double answer;


first = x - (pow(x, 3.0) / 3.0);
answer = first + (pow(x, 5.0) / 5.0);
answer = answer - specialx;


while (x = x) {

    if (answer == answer - specialx) {

        y += 2;
        answer = answer + specialx;
        return answer;
    }

    if (answer == answer + specialx) {

        y += 2;
        answer = answer - specialx;
        return answer;
}

}
        return answer;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about while loop condition

> while(x=x)

Its not comparison instead an assignment operation.

Even after you fix the condition in while loop you will still be in infinite loop as if conditions will never be met with Logic written.

Are you Looking for solution to find ctan or bug in code that you have pasted ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Id like to be able to turn this into a proper program but if not id be willing to start from scratch, what do you recommend I use instead of the while loop and what conditions should I use for the changing of the signs?

Comment: Actually I see what you mean, it should be x==x right? Isnt Arctan supposed to be infinite from what the code looks like? I'm pretty confused so any help will be appreciated haha

Answer (score 0):

```
if (answer == answer - specialx)
```

and

```
if (answer == answer + specialx)
```

will never evaluate to be true.

Because for example,
Lets say answer equals to 5 and specialx equals to 3,
5 does not equal to 5 - 3
and
5 does not equal to 5 + 3 as well

Comment: Thank you for replying, what would you recommend I use instead for the conditions?